# Como consigo obter o maior valor de uma matriz com função Lambda em Python

Tags: python, matriz, expressões-lambda

Em uma lista é possível com o método "reduce" conseguir o maior valor, porém em uma matriz não estou conseguir obter o maior valor dela:

```
from functools import reduce

matriz = [[4, 2, 56], [7, 46, 10], [3, 89, 2]]
print(matriz)
result = reduce((lambda x , y: x if (x > y) else y), matriz)
print(result)
```

O resultado que tenho é:

```
[7, 46, 10]
```

Gostaria de puxar um único valor dentro de toda a matriz que seja o maior dentre o restante.

Comment: É obrigatório o uso de matriz? Pode ser uma matriz convertida?

Comment: Sim, é obrigatório o uso de matriz.

Comment: Mas é obrigatório o uso de `reduce` ?

Comment: Não, desde que permaneça com a função lambda para encontrar o menor valor da lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sua `matriz` é uma lista de listas (uma lista na qual cada elemento é outra lista), usar `reduce` desta forma vai percorrer somente o primeiro nível (ou seja, você estará comparando se uma lista é maior que outra). Para comparar os números, você pode usar o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

matriz = [[4, 2, 56], [7, 46, 10], [3, 89, 2]]
result = reduce(lambda x , y: x if x > y else y, chain.from_iterable(matriz))
print(result) # 89
```

[`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) pega todas as sub-listas e as transformam em um único iterável, no qual cada elemento será um dos números. Assim, você consegue compará-los corretamente com o *lambda* (repare também que os parênteses em volta do *labmda* são redundantes e podem ser removidos).

---

Você disse [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/473784/como-consigo-obter-o-maior-valor-de-uma-matriz-com-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-lambda-em-python#comment890403_473784) que usar `reduce` não é obrigatório, somente o *lambda*. Sendo assim, poderia ser feito um *loop* simples:

```
matriz = [[4, 2, 56], [7, 46, 10], [3, 89, 2]]
maior = lambda x , y: x if x > y else y
result = float('-inf')
for linha in matriz:
    for numero in linha:
        result = maior(result, numero)
print(result) # 89
```

O detalhe é que eu inicio `result` com "menos infinito" (o menor valor possível), assim na primeira comparação o primeiro elemento da matriz com certeza será maior que ele. Nas demais iterações, ele compara o `result` com cada elemento, e no final temos o maior.

---

Obs: se não fosse obrigatório usar o *lambda*, seria mais simples usar [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), juntamente com `chain.from_iterable`:

```
result = max(chain.from_iterable(matriz))
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode iterar a sua matriz dentro do segundo argumento do reduce:

```py
from functools import reduce
matriz = [[4, 2, 56], [7, 46, 10], [3, 89, 2]]
print(matriz)
result = reduce((lambda x , y: x if (x > y) else y), [item for sublista in matriz for item in sublista])
print(result)
```

Saída:

```py
[[4, 2, 56], [7, 46, 10], [3, 89, 2]]
89
```